# Excel Pivot table Grand Average that includes 0's in total average

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, measure, dynamic-pivot

I have a custom **Measure** in my **excel data model** so I can calculate **Grand Average in a pivot table**...

`MyMeasure:=VAR T1 =`

`SUMMARIZE(HC_Data,HC_Data[data date (Month)], "Total HC", [Count of NAME]) RETURN`

`IF(HASONEVALUE(HC_Data[data date (Month)]), SUM(HC_Data[HC count]), AVERAGEX( T1, [Total HC]))`

now, at first sight, this works wonders! BUT, it doesn't take into accounts months with 0's since the source data wouldn't have a record if there is a 0 in the pivot table.

The pivot table will show a **0** since the columns months are based on a full calendar, and pivot set to show **0** when there is no record. so what i need is a way that the custom **Measure** accounts for **0's**.. is this possible?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create a new table comprising a unique list of entries from the *data date (Month)* column and create a relationship between this new table and *HC_Data*. You can then amend your measure to:

```
MyMeasure:=VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE( Months, Months[Month], "Total HC",[Count of NAME] )
RETURN
    IF(
        HASONEVALUE( HC_Data[data date (Month)] ),
        SUM( HC_Data[HC count] ),
        AVERAGEX( T1, [Total HC] )
    )
```

I have assumed that the new table is called *Months* and comprises a single column called *Month*.

Comment: unfortunately, this did not work